# Google push notifications - DOMException: Registration failed - permission denied

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following the  ([getting started with push locations guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-06?hl=en)) but am running into an error on step 6:

```
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - permission denied
```

My manifest.json file is loading correctly based on the Network tab.

I have entered my correct project number into manifest.json. I have tried adding other settings not mentioned in the guide:

```
{
  "name": "Push Notifications codelab",
  "gcm_sender_id": "123456789",
  "gcm_user_visible_only": true,
  "permissions": [
    "gcm"
  ]
}
```

I am running my server on localhost as per the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was actually in my settings for Chrome. Under **Content Settings**,  **Notifications** was set to *Do not allow any site to show notifications*. Changing this setting to *Ask when a site wants to show notifications* resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Brave(the browser) and having the same issue, you have to enable **[Use Google Services for Push Messaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5hGq.png)** in the settings.

In order to enable it:

`Brave settings > Privacy and Security > Use Google Services for Push Messaging`

or use `brave://settings/privacy` shortcut.

Comment: The brave browser's market share is marginal. Why would you provide a supposed answer specific to this browser, when the OP did not mention it?

Comment: @AmitaiIrron because I had the same issue and after-hours facing the same error, I fixed it by tweaking the setting.

Comment: Yay, I'm a marginal. And this answer helped me, so upvote (regardless that the browser wasn't part of the question) - interestingly it does work in Private mode without setting the switch - go figure!

Comment: I use Brave and if not for this I would have lost yet another day trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

[`DOMException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/DOMException.html) occurs when an operation is impossible to perform, either for logical reasons, because data is lost, or because the implementation has become unstable. You got your error **DOMException: Registration failed - permission denied** maybe because the manifest was loaded from a different domain than the main page. Suggested from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966529/uncaught-in-promise-domexception-registration-failed-manifest-empty-or-miss), try to use `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` if your page is not located at the root of the website. You can also check on this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782247/gcm-to-chrome-general-help-unable-to-subscribe-no-sender-id).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I believe manifest.json is loading correctly already as I get a resource not found error if I change it to use `/manifest.json`. The other SO question you referenced also does not seem to contain the answer.